# Best idea for storing groups with users in database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create app that have some groups and every group have some users. For CRUD operation I should use SQLite database. How should I store them in database?

Is a logic way to create a seperate database for each group and save users in them?
Any other idea?

Comment: This is database design and beyond the scope of this site. Show what you've tried and ask for specific problems.

Answer (score 6):

This is a standard design: One table with the groups, another with the users. If a user has only one group add is as foreign key in the user table. If a user belongs to multiple groups add a 3rd table with the n:m relation group table to user table.